# REORGANIZE seems to work as well as REBUILD all the time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, index

On this [MSDN Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858(v=sql.110).aspx) it says if you should reorganize or rebuild based on the amount of fragmentation:

```
 5% to 30%   ->   ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE  
 Over 30%    ->   ALTER INDEX REBUILD WITH (ONLINE = ON)*
```

However, we have noticed that even with really high fragmentation (over 95%) on large and small tables, REORGANIZE works fine.  (The fragmentation goes down to less that 1%).

Why does the MSDN page say this?  Is it not supposed to work like it is for me?

**Or is there a drawback I am missing?  (A hidden problem if I don't rebuild?)**

Comment: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/where-do-the-books-online-index-fragmentation-thresholds-come-from/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let me quote another part of that same page, which basically says **IT DEPENDS** - emphasis mine:

> These values provide a ***rough guideline*** for determining the point at which you should switch between ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE and ALTER INDEX REBUILD. However, the actual values ***may vary from case to case***. It is important that **you experiment to determine the best threshold for *your* environment**.

There's not really a good answer for this except "it depends"... those are just ***general guidelines*** and may or may not be appropriate depending on the number of rows, the columns in your index, their data types, how wide the index is, what else is getting written to disk in between writes to those tables, etc.

Like how big should I size tempdb, what is a good threshold for PLE, and what type of car should I buy, the answer is the same: **IT DEPENDS**.

Comment: If it was not working, then it would not lower the fragmentation?  (IE: As long as the fragmentation goes down we don't need to worry?)

Comment: @Vaccano Some would say you don't need to worry about fragmentation anyway. See [this article](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2012/08/sql-server-index-fragmentation/) and [this article](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/11/index-fragmentation-matter/). I'm not suggesting you should ignore it, but it seems you're putting more thought into this than you need to. Do you have any actual evidence of actual performance problems when the index is highly fragmented? And that those problems disappear once you've "fixed" it? Do you stop at the gas station every morning and check tire pressure?

Comment: Yeah, I have read that too.  But we have noticed a bit of a performance improvement when we keep them de-fragmented.  The fragmentation is fairly predictable (table and time) so we are just going to automate it.  I just wanted to make sure that I am OK with the REORGANIZE over the REBUILD before it gets automated.

Comment: @Vaccano What does "a bit" mean? How exactly have you tied these things together? Perhaps a subsequent query is faster because the index operation pulled all of the data into memory, so the query didn't have to do that. Perhaps it was that a new plan was generated based on updated statistics, that may or may not be a manual part of your maintenance. I'm not convinced that you are able to tie performance improvements directly to the act of defragmentation, especially when you don't see any difference in fragmentation reduction between rebuild and reorganize.

Comment: And again, I am absolutely not saying that you shouldn't defragment, or that it should be ignored. Just be sure you're giving it the credit it deserves, and not assuming that doing it (or not doing it) absolutely must directly affect performance.

Comment: You are correct that we don't have a provable performance metric to fragmenting.  (I did not think about the reorg pulling it into memory.)   We are not overly emphasizing defragmenting.  Just trying to keep it down along with all the other stuff we do.

Answer (score 7):

The big difference, in my environment, is that Reorganize is single threaded, and Rebuild can go as parallel as you have processors. Rebuild also has the added bonus of updating your statistics, so you can forgo separate statistics updates where you've rebuilt.

From my perspective, dealing with some big (100GB to multi-terabyte) tables, I pretty much set everything to rebuild. I've watched Reorganize spend 8 hours on one PK (300GB table) and barely make a dent. I'm solely responsible for about 100TB of data across 8 servers, and our maintenance windows are not the longest (1am - 7am).

I currently use [Ola Hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) scripts, but I am looking to make a move to [Minion Reindex](http://www.midnightsql.com/minion/) in the coming months, since they offer the ability to pre-fetch the objects you'd like to work on, so the whole maintenance window can be spent on maintenance, rather than gathering fragmentation data. The [function that gathers fragmentation data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx) can run for quite a while, even in LIMITED mode, on larger tables.

Answer (score 7):

@AaronBertrand has a very good answer and is correct - ***it depends.*** I'd like to add that you're only looking at one metric - index fragmentation. That's a good start, but there are other things to consider.

Consider the following scenario (using AdventureWorks2014):

```
select * 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where SalesOrderID < 50000;

--modify
delete 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where SalesOrderID < 50000;
go

select 
    SchemaName = s.name,
    TableName = t.name, 
    IndexName = idx.name, 
    StatsName = st.name, 
    AvgFragmentationPct = idx.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    StatsModifications = st.modification_counter,
    StatsPctModified = 100.*st.modification_counter / st.unfiltered_rows,
    StatsSampleRate = st.sample_rate, 
    StatsLastUpdate = st.last_updated,
    Rows = st.rows
from (
    select s.object_id, s.name, sp.modification_counter, sp.unfiltered_rows, s.stats_id, sp.last_updated, sample_rate = (100.*sp.rows_sampled)/sp.unfiltered_rows , sp.rows
    from sys.stats s 
    cross apply sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id,s.stats_id) sp 
) st
left join (
        select ips.object_id, i.name, ips.partition_number, ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent, i.index_id
        from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),null, null, null, default) ips
        join sys.indexes i 
            on ips.index_id = i.index_id
            and ips.object_id = i.object_id
        ) idx
on st.object_id = idx.object_id
    and st.stats_id = idx.index_id
join sys.tables t 
    on st.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.schemas s
    on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where s.name = 'Sales' and t.name = 'SalesOrderDetail'
go

delete 
from Sales.SalesOrderDetail
where ProductID = 779
go

select 
    SchemaName = s.name,
    TableName = t.name, 
    IndexName = idx.name, 
    StatsName = st.name, 
    AvgFragmentationPct = idx.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    StatsModifications = st.modification_counter,
    StatsPctModified = 100.*st.modification_counter / st.unfiltered_rows,
    StatsSampleRate = st.sample_rate, 
    StatsLastUpdate = st.last_updated,
    Rows = st.rows
from (
    select s.object_id, s.name, sp.modification_counter, sp.unfiltered_rows, s.stats_id, sp.last_updated, sample_rate = (100.*sp.rows_sampled)/sp.unfiltered_rows , sp.rows
    from sys.stats s 
    cross apply sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id,s.stats_id) sp 
) st
left join (
        select ips.object_id, i.name, ips.partition_number, ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent, i.index_id
        from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),null, null, null, default) ips
        join sys.indexes i 
            on ips.index_id = i.index_id
            and ips.object_id = i.object_id
        ) idx
on st.object_id = idx.object_id
    and st.stats_id = idx.index_id
join sys.tables t 
    on st.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.schemas s
    on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where s.name = 'Sales' and t.name = 'SalesOrderDetail'
go
```

We create a new auto-created statistics object (`_WA_Sys_00000006_44CA3770`, in this example) by filtering on `SalesOrderID` and then we delete rows (~30,000 of them). We then introduce further modifications by deleting rows with a specific `ProductID`. This is important because it's a leading column in at least one of these indexes/stats which, in turn, is important for selectivity calculation reasons (statistics), and b-tree traversal (index).

[image]

The index fragmentation isn't so bad, so let's reorganize.

```
alter index all on Sales.SalesOrderDetail reorganize;
go

select 
    SchemaName = s.name,
    TableName = t.name, 
    IndexName = idx.name, 
    StatsName = st.name, 
    AvgFragmentationPct = idx.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    StatsModifications = st.modification_counter,
    StatsPctModified = 100.*st.modification_counter / st.unfiltered_rows,
    StatsSampleRate = st.sample_rate, 
    StatsLastUpdate = st.last_updated,
    Rows = st.rows
from (
    select s.object_id, s.name, sp.modification_counter, sp.unfiltered_rows, s.stats_id, sp.last_updated, sample_rate = (100.*sp.rows_sampled)/sp.unfiltered_rows , sp.rows
    from sys.stats s 
    cross apply sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id,s.stats_id) sp 
) st
left join (
        select ips.object_id, i.name, ips.partition_number, ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent, i.index_id
        from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),null, null, null, default) ips
        join sys.indexes i 
            on ips.index_id = i.index_id
            and ips.object_id = i.object_id
        ) idx
on st.object_id = idx.object_id
    and st.stats_id = idx.index_id
join sys.tables t 
    on st.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.schemas s
    on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where s.name = 'Sales' and t.name = 'SalesOrderDetail'
go
```

[image]

There are no changes wrought by a reorganization.

Let's rebuild:

```
alter index all on Sales.SalesOrderDetail rebuild;
go

select 
    SchemaName = s.name,
    TableName = t.name, 
    IndexName = idx.name, 
    StatsName = st.name, 
    AvgFragmentationPct = idx.avg_fragmentation_in_percent,
    StatsModifications = st.modification_counter,
    StatsPctModified = 100.*st.modification_counter / st.unfiltered_rows,
    StatsSampleRate = st.sample_rate, 
    StatsLastUpdate = st.last_updated,
    Rows = st.rows
from (
    select s.object_id, s.name, sp.modification_counter, sp.unfiltered_rows, s.stats_id, sp.last_updated, sample_rate = (100.*sp.rows_sampled)/sp.unfiltered_rows , sp.rows
    from sys.stats s 
    cross apply sys.dm_db_stats_properties(s.object_id,s.stats_id) sp 
) st
left join (
        select ips.object_id, i.name, ips.partition_number, ips.avg_fragmentation_in_percent, i.index_id
        from sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(db_id(),null, null, null, default) ips
        join sys.indexes i 
            on ips.index_id = i.index_id
            and ips.object_id = i.object_id
        ) idx
on st.object_id = idx.object_id
    and st.stats_id = idx.index_id
join sys.tables t 
    on st.object_id = t.object_id
join sys.schemas s
    on t.schema_id = s.schema_id
where s.name = 'Sales' and t.name = 'SalesOrderDetail'
go
```

[image]

Ok, our fragmentation numbers are modestly better but not significant and, to your point, perhaps not worth the overhead of rebuilding over reorganization.

There are a few other things worth noting, though.

1. Rebuilding your indexes also updates your statistics with a fullscan. It should be noted that it ***only*** updates the statistics that support the index - no other statistics are updated (as evidenced by the sad state of `_WA_Sys_00000006_44CA3770`).
2. Reorganizing your index does not update your statistics in any capacity

**Conclusion**

There's more to evaluate than whether or not you're getting good defragmentation rates. While certainly important to IO, I've also found it quite helpful to explore my systems and see if I can ascertain how to best maintain it, rather than updating, rebuilding, and reorganizing blindly.